# SQL Server gives me a different result

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

```
;with sub as
(
    select 
        x.*,
        row_number() over(partition by wdl order by id) - row_number() over(order by id) as grp
    from 
        (select 
             id, hometeam as team, wdl 
         from 
             #HomeTeam_vs_AwayTeam
         where 
             hometeam = @Team

         union all

         select 
             id, awayteam,wdl
         from 
             #HomeTeam_vs_AwayTeam
         where 
             awayteam = @Team) x
)
INSERT INTO #Team_Streak([Team], [WDL], [Streak])
   (select 
        team, wdl, count(*) as count
    from 
        sub
    where 
        grp = (select grp from sub where id = (select max(id) from sub))
    group by 
        team, wdl)
```

Why does this query give me a different result and sometimes gives me two results?

I'm using SQL Server 2012

Comment: Look at the data.  It will be obvious.

Comment: I think a better question is what is this query supposed to do? Also is `id` unique on `#HomeTeam_vs_AwayTeam`. For a given `id`, can the same team be home and away?

Comment: Its count last @team streak the data is good i have accurate count on some teams for some i have two results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic problem is that the way `grp` is calculated doesn't put streaks into unique groups.
Take the following data in `#HomeTeam_vs_AwayTeam`, for example:

```
id | hometeam | awayteam | wdl
---+----------+----------+----
 1 | team A   | team B   | W
 2 | team A   | team B   | L
 3 | team A   | team B   | W
```

if you look at what sub generates for this it is:

```
id | team   | wdl | grp
---+--------+-----+----
 1 | team A | W   | 0
 2 | team A | L   | -1
 3 | team A | W   | -1
```

I.e `grp -1` has values for `W` and `L`. This is because `row_number() over (partition by wdl order by id)` doesn't reset between streaks. [Example SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f1e8e/1)

One way to fix it is below, although it feels like this should be able to be simplified

```
with results as (
    select 
        id, hometeam as team, wdl 
    from 
        #HomeTeam_vs_AwayTeam
    where 
        hometeam = @Team
    union all
    select 
        id, awayteam,wdl 
        -- wdl should probably be 
        -- case wdl when 'W' then 'L' when 'D' then 'D' when 'L' then 'W' end
    from 
        #HomeTeam_vs_AwayTeam
    where 
        awayteam = @Team
), sub as (
    select 
        results.*,
        row_number() over(order by id) as rn,
        lag(wdl) over (order by id) as prev_wdl
    from
        results
), limits as (
    select
        max(id) id,
        max(rn) - max(case when wdl != prev_wdl then rn else 1 end) + 1 streak
    from
        sub
) select
    results.team,
    results.wdl,
    limits.streak
from
    limits
        inner join
    results
        on limits.id = results.id
```

[Example SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8feec/14)